# Smooth compactification of complex varieties and uniqueness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Since I'm working in differential geometry, for the following I'm strictly interested in the smooth setting over $\mathbb{C}$ and its relation to the setting over $\mathbb{R}$.

Here are a few useful definitions/conventions. All spaces are connected.

**Definition 1:** An open manifold is a smooth non-compact manifold without boundary. A closed manifold is a smooth compact manifold without boundary.

**Definition 2:** A smooth manifold $M$ is *tame* if it is diffeomorphic to the interior of a smooth compact manifold $N$ with (possibly empty) boundary. $N$ is called a *compactification* of $M$.

So according to these definitions, a tame manifold can be either open or closed; in fact all closed manifolds trivially are tame. Thus only open tame manifolds are of interest.

Let $X$ be a smooth affine complex algebraic variety. For my purposes I think of $X$ as a complex open manifold that happens to be algebraic. My main question is whether $X$ is always tame, and if so, when is its compactification unique (up to diffeomorphism)?

I am aware of the following results. From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4083521/354855), we get that a manifold $M$ is (real) algebraic if and only if it is tame. This doesn't seem to necessarily imply that the compactification of $M$ is unique. In fact, it might very well not be, [see this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/81724/143629).

From [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_completion), we get that for $X$ a smooth affine algebraic curve over a perfect field $k$, there exists a unique smooth compactification, although there they define a compactification to mean an ambient compact space for which $X$ is merely an open subset. So we get uniqueness, but a priori $X$ need not be tame. In the 'generalizations' section of the same wiki article, it provides the same result for higher dimensions but dropping the uniqueness result. But again, the property of being tame isn't immediately satisfied.

I am interested in clarifying these results, particularly whether tame-ness and uniqueness is achieved in all cases, and to know if there is an overarching theorem classifying tame affine complex varieties (perhaps involving results from resolution of singularities, which I know little about).

Comment: Any smooth affine complex algebraic variety $X$ admits a smooth compactification (by resolution of singularities), and this compactification is never unique if $\dim(X)\geq 2$, because you can always blow up a point in the boundary.

Comment: @abx Good to know. So in particular there can be two non-diffeomorphic compactifications of $X$? Also could you suggest a good introductory reference to this result on resolution of singularities?

Comment: Yes to the first question. There is a huge literature on the second one, see the bibliography in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_of_singularities).

Comment: To add to abx's answer, resolution of singularities gives you a smooth compactification in the algebraic sense ($X$ is a dense Zariski open subset of a smooth compact variety). To get a compactification in the differential-topological sense ($X$ is the interior of a manifold-with-boundary) you need to take the real-oriented blow-up of the boundary of an algebraic compactification. This gives you a manifold-with-corners.

Comment: @DanPetersen I see, and what if we want to avoid corners in our manifolds? Is that possible as well, i.e. this is an option among the non-unique compactifications?