# How far can one reconstruct the boundary of a manifold M given its interior $int M$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

Suppose I keep in my pocket a manifold with boundary $M$ , and I provide you access to $int M := M \setminus \partial M$ up to homeomorphism/diffeomorphism. What can you deduce about $\partial M$? can you reconstruct it up to homotopy/homeomorphism/diffeomorphism? can you deduce homotopical / topologial / smooth invariants of it?

Comment: Did you want to say that $M$ is compact?

Comment: Consider closed interval $[0,1]$. It's interior is topologically equivalent to the real line.

Comment: Adding boundaries to open manifolds has been discussed at least in these previous questions: [22441](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22441), [34602](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34602), [81714](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81714), [83356](http://mathoverflow.net/q/83356), [158391](http://mathoverflow.net/q/158391). So in a sense this is a duplicate.

Comment: This is basically the same as the following previous question: http://mathoverflow.net/q/81714/317