# Compactification of open manifolds in the form of a manifold( with zero Euler characteristic)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, euler-characteristics

**Edit:** According to the interesting comments of Michael Albanese and Nick L we revise the question as follows:

By manifold compactification of a manifold $M$ we mean a compact manifold $\tilde{M}$ which contains $M$  as an open dense subset.

Assume that $M$ is an open connected manifold which admits a manifold compactification.
Does $M$  necessarily admit a manifold compactification with zero Euler characteristic?

Comment: Pinch a torus and remove the pinch point. The result is an open connected manifold. How would you compactify this so that the result is a manifold?

Comment: @Neal: Once you remove the pinch point, what's left is homeomorphic to a cylinder which embeds in a torus.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I was thinking too rigidly. Thank you.

Comment: I guess you want to assume that $M$ has finite topological type (for example it has CW complex structure with finite number of cells). Otherwise it can never embed in a compact manifold (consider surface with infinite genus for example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compactification of a manifold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34602/compactification-of-a-manifold)

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thank you for sharing the link. I revise the question with emphasize on on "zero Euler characteristic.

Comment: No. The complement of a point in an oriented surface of genus 2 cannot be embedded in a torus or a Klein bottle.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie  what is the reason of this non embedding property?Are you using relative homology? However this non embedding is obvious intutively but i can not find a proof for that.Thanks for your attention to my question.

Comment: Perhaps use the fact that the genus two surface contains a separating curve which is non-trivial in $\pi_{1}$, You just have to prove that the class of this curve doesn't die in the compactification.

Comment: @NickL  But the  comment of  Prof. Goodwillie says there is  no an open set of the torus homeomorphic to the  $M_2 \setminus \{pt\}$. He does  not  consider  compactification. BTW  waht is  that separating  non trivial closed curve on $M_2$.

Comment: If one connect sums two tori to get a genus two surface, then this separating curve is the curve that corresponds to the boundary of the two disks that were cut out to make the connect sum.

Comment: Probably it would have been more accurate to say "the class of this curve doesn't die in the embedding" (This argument wouldn't rely on the image being dense).

Comment: @NickL But I think that the curve you mentioned is a trivial loop. Am I correct?

Comment: No it is trivial in homology but non-trivial in the fundamenetal group. This is discussed here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031069/homologous-to-zero-but-not-contractible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First note that odd dimensions the question of Euler characteristic $0$ is automatic, $M$ will embed in the orientable double cover of $\tilde{M}$, which will have $\chi = 0$ by Poincare Duality.

In even dimension = $2n$ (we assume $n > 1$), we recall the following fact. If $M_{1},M_{2}$ are compact connected manifolds then $\chi(M_{1} \# M_{2}) = \chi(M_{1}) + \chi(M_{2}) - \chi(S^{2n}) = \chi(M_{1}) + \chi(M_{2}) - 2$.

To prove that some embedding into any manifold implies embedding in to Euler characteristic $0$ manifold, it is sufficient to show that any integer is equal to the Euler characteristic of some manifold of dimension $2n$, since we can do connect sums on the complement of the embedding $M \hookrightarrow \tilde{M}$ (It is easy to see that the embedding can be changed so that this complement contains an open set) to shift the Euler characteristic of $\tilde{M}$ to the correct value.

In dimension $4$ we have $\chi(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{2} \times \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{2}) =1$ and $\chi(\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}^{2} ) = 3$. So for any $4$-manifold $N$ connect summing with $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{2} \times \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{2}$ subtracts 1 from $\chi(N)$, connect summing with $\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}^{2} $ adds one to $\chi(N)$, hence there is a $4$-manifold with Euler characteristic equal to any integer. In higher even dimension taking appropriate products with $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{2}$ will give the same result.

**Edit 1** As Misha points out we can now ensure the image is dense by using the fact that every connected n-manifold is a compactification of an open n-cell.

**Edit 2**. Note that the above solution holds in even dimensions atleast $4$. I will give details a counterexample in the dimension $2$ case (which was pointed out Tom Goodwillie).

Let $S$ be an orientable surface of genus $g \geq 2$. I will show there is no embedding $I: S \setminus \{p\} \hookrightarrow S'$ (for some $p \in S$). Where $S'$ is a compact surface of Euler characteristic $0$ (i.e. a torus or a Klein bottle).

We argue by contractiction, suppose such an embedding $I$, exists. Let $C$ be the boundary of a small neighbourhood of $p$.

Suppose there is an embbeding $I: S \setminus \{p\} \hookrightarrow S' $, then image of $I(C)$ decomposes $S'$ as the connect sum of $S$ and compact surface $\Sigma$. In symbols: $S' = S \# \Sigma$. Hence by the formula for Euler characteristic of a connect sum given above $\chi(S') \leq -2$.

To see this note by the classification of surfaces $\chi(\Sigma) \leq 2$ and by direct computation $\chi(S) = 2-2g \leq -2$, the fact that $\chi(S') \leq -2$ now follows directly from the formula for Euler characteristic of a connect sum. This is the desired contradiction.

Comment: You can easily complete your solution by using the fact that every connected n-manifold is a compactification of an open n-cell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.And I thank you @Misha for your comment.

Comment: @Misha: will you please elaborate your comment: how does the fact you quoted help to find a *dense* embedding out of an open embedding? I would say one needs a more general "every connected n-manifold is a compactification of (any manifold diffeomorphic to) any nonempty open subset of its" (which I think is also true).